# Serialize Object Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, web-services

I have following table structure in LINQ:

[image]

objective_id is foreign key in Resource table which is PK in Objective table.

I wanted to have output like this:

```
{
    ID: '123',
    user_id: '1',
    skill_id:'1',
    name:'abcs'
    ...
    objective_resource: 
    {
        ID: '123',
        ...
    }
}
```

**For this i tried:**

```
 using (DataTableClassesDataContext context = new DataTableClassesDataContext())
            {
                DataLoadOptions opts = new DataLoadOptions();
                opts.LoadWith<objective_resource>(u => u.objective_id);
                context.LoadOptions = opts;

                return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(context.objective_resources
                    .Where(u => u.id == 1)
                    );
            }
```

But It given output:

```
        {
            ID: '123',
            ...

objective:
  {

        ID: '123',
        user_id: '1',
        skill_id:'1',
        name:'abcs'
        ...

    }
 }
```

I wanted to have:

```
{
        ID: '123',
        user_id: '1',
        skill_id:'1',
        name:'abcs'
        ...
        objective_resource: 
        {
            ID: '123',
            ...
        }
    }
```

Please help me.

How can i get the output???

Comment: Curious, is there a Data Annotation in your POCO ?

Comment: no, sir its not present

Comment: @BillGreer The JSON is correct, he is seriaising a single objective_resource and it's associated parent objective.

Comment: @BenRobinson: yep. If he does opts.LoadWith<objective>(u => u.id); it has a better chance of working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the change in association property in dbml file as

[image]

and write the code as

```
var data= dataContext.objectives;
return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
```